# Connection giving an identification of the double-tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $M$ be a manifold, and let $\nabla$ be a (possibly torsion-free) connection on $M$. Then I am pretty sure that $\nabla$ induces an isomorphism between the double-tangent bundle and the Whitney sum of two copies of the tangent bundle
$$T_{(m,\hat{m})}TM\cong T_mM\oplus T_mM$$
as follows: let an element of $T_{(m,\hat{m})}TM$ be given as the equivalence class of a path $(\gamma(t),v(t))$ in $TM$, i.e. $v(t)\in T_{\gamma(t)}M$. Then we identify
$$[\gamma(t),v(t)] = \left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t),\nabla_tv(0)\right),$$
where the covariant derivative is taken along the path. However, I am not really sure how to start to prove this statement. Does anyone have any ideas or hints?

Comment: google for ehresmann connection induced by koszul connection or something.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838600/splitting-of-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-vector-bundle-and-connections. That question refers to "Connections, curvature, and cohomology. Vol. 2: Lie groups, principal bundles, characteristic classes", chapter VII.6 (page 335).